# Exoplayer Dolby playback issues with dynamic ad insertion

Tags: android, exoplayer, interstitial, mpeg-dash, amazon-fire-tv

Im playing a DAI supported DASH stream with Exoplayer 2.18.1 (on firetv 4k) where the multi-period manifest gets stitched with the ad period. The ad period sometimes have dolby (stereo or 5.1) audio tracks and when the playback switches to ad from live we see some video freezes and then complete playback freeze at the end of the ad. The `adb logcat` at this time show following `spurious audio timestamp` related logs:

```
09-21 17:34:57.312 19192 23498 W AudioTrack: Spurious audio timestamp (frame position mismatch): 28270119, 10923744015, 10923743917, 189528000, 9827328, 9827328
09-21 17:34:57.816 19192 23498 W AudioTrack: Spurious audio timestamp (frame position mismatch): 28294325, 10924248296, 10924248198, 189528000, 9827328, 9827328
09-21 17:34:58.211 19192 19231 V SessionStateManager: 2022-09-21 17:34:58,211 - Thread: [main] - player time 1663761496000ms program start time 1663759800000ms media session time 1696000ms
09-21 17:34:58.211 19192 19231 V SessionStateManager: 2022-09-21 17:34:58,211 - Thread: [main] - com.mobitv.client.connect.core.media.session.MobiMediaSession@34d0ee4 set media session playback state to PLAYING time 1696000ms
09-21 17:34:58.211 19192 19231 V SessionStateManager: 2022-09-21 17:34:58,211 - Thread: [main] - setting playback state PlaybackState {state=3, position=1696000, buffered position=0, speed=1.0, updated=10924643, actions=8963, error code=0, error message=null, custom actions=[], active item id=-1}
09-21 17:34:58.213   739   932 V Avrcp   : MediaController playback changed: PlaybackState {state=3, position=1696000, buffered position=0, speed=1.0, updated=10924643, actions=8963, custom actions=[], active item id=-1, error=null}
09-21 17:34:58.322 19192 23498 W AudioTrack: Spurious audio timestamp (frame position mismatch): 28318587, 10924753767, 10924753671, 189528000, 9827328, 9827328
```

One interesting thing to note is that this exact ad plays well when played individually i.e like a DASH VoD asset but not when stitched with DASH live period.

Some more information from stitched manifest that might help. The live period contains 1 video and 1 audio track:

```
<Representation id="L_5000_W" codecs="avc1.64001f" bandwidth="5120000" width="1280" height="720" frameRate="60/2" sar="1:1">
 <SegmentTemplate initialization="$RepresentationID$/init.mp4" media="$RepresentationID$/$Time$.m4s" timescale="90000" presentationTimeOffset="150764576748000">
    ...
 </SegmentTemplate>
</Representation>

<Representation id="L_384_ENG" codecs="ac-3" bandwidth="384000" audioSamplingRate="48000">
 <AudioChannelConfiguration schemeIdUri="tag:dolby.com,2014:dash:audio_channel_configuration:2011" value="F801"/>
  <SegmentTemplate initialization="$RepresentationID$/init.mp4" media="$RepresentationID$/$Time$.m4s" timescale="48000" presentationTimeOffset="80407774265537">
     ...
  </SegmentTemplate>
</Representation>
```

The ad period too contains 1 video and 1 audio track:

```
<Representation id="A_5000_W" codecs="avc1.4d4028" bandwidth="5120000" width="1920" height="1080" frameRate="60/2" sar="1:1">
 <SegmentTemplate initialization="/prod-ad-1/$RepresentationID$/init.mp4" media="/prod-ad-1/$RepresentationID$/$Number$.m4s" timescale="90000" startNumber="1">
   ...             
 </SegmentTemplate>
</Representation>

<Representation id="A_384_ENG" codecs="ac-3" bandwidth="384000" audioSamplingRate="48000">
 <AudioChannelConfiguration schemeIdUri="tag:dolby.com,2014:dash:audio_channel_configuration:2011" value="F801"/>
   <SegmentTemplate initialization="/prod-ad-1/$RepresentationID$/init.mp4" media="/prod-ad-1/$RepresentationID$/$Number$.m4s" timescale="48000" startNumber="1">
     ...
   </SegmentTemplate>
</Representation>
```

As of now Im struggling to understand the exact reasons for this playback problem. Can any please one help understanding this issue ?

Edit: FireTV stick 4K with Fire OS 6.2.9.3 (NS6293/4731)

Comment: You should document which Fire TV device/OS version you are testing on.

Comment: It is a FireTV stick 4K with Fire OS 6.2.9.3 (NS6293/4731).

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your mediaSource with a Factory that joins media items. There are options like `MergingMediaSource` and `ConcatenatingMediaSource`. The first one worked for adMob ads, but I had to use the later one when the server was adding ads in the uri media playlist.

```
mediaSource = ConcatenatingMediaSource(
  mediaSource!!,
  *mediaSourceList.toTypedArray()
)
```